# .near/mainnet/data" thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to open the database: DBError(Error { message: "Corruption: Can't access /3700449.sst: IO error

Tags: nearprotocol

what i am actually doing, getting new node

1. downloaded archive data for mainnet from "https://near-protocol-public.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/backups/mainnet/archive/data.tar"
2. I switched to github release version 1.22.0
3. Compiled the neard
4. Stopped Near  "nearup stop"
5. tar -xvf data.tar -C ~/.near/mainnet/data
6. nearup start mainnet

then i got the error
.near/mainnet/data"
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to open the database: DBError(Error { message: "Corruption: Can't access /3700449.sst: IO error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you I understand you right, that you have overwritten the existing `data` folder from a previously running node? That really a road to failure. Remove the `data` folder before extracting the backup